# Count number of words in txt/doc/docx file using PHP

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I want to use **google docs php API** to upload file of any format(docx/doc) and export it to the txt format so that i can count number of words easily .

**My Problem :**
[Google Docs PHP API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html) does not provide support for exporting files as [Java API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) does .

Can anyone suggest some good way of doing this, since I am really new to PHP world.